# angular 5 bootstrap 4 bootswatch theming doesn't work

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootswatch

I have problems with using bootswatch themes with angular 5 and bootstrap 4
I added in styles.scss

```
    @import "~bootswatch/dist/cerulean/variables";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
    @import "~bootswatch/dist/cerulean/bootswatch";
```

In app.component.html for test I added

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Colors stayed as in original bootstrap color scheme

I also tried to add scripts block inside .angular-cli.json

```
    "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"],
```

still without success.

Any ideas how to use boostwatch scss version adn angular cli?

Answer (score 0):

Theme works.
I was mislead by looking only at navbar colors which didn't changed because I used "bg-light" instead of "bg-primary" like on bootswatch doc.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
```

instead of

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary">
```